# Capture an email using PHP

Tags: php, email

I have created a simple php file to capture emails from users who are signing up for a newsletter.  The 'captured email' is not getting sent through to me.  The email I receive is this 'Email: ' without the users email.

```
<?php

session_start();
//require_once('recaptchalib.php');
$privatekey = "6Ldni7wUAAAAAIMRGmqhTeehXqkx0ZC";
$publickey = "6Ldni7wUAAAAAKO37aO2hfy3kHyXTuN";

$email = $_POST['email'];

$admin_email = 'example@email.com';
$email_from = 'example@email.com';
$email_subject = "Newsletter Signup";
$email_body = "Email: $email \r\n";
$to = "$admin_email";
$headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
$headers = "Reply-To: $email \r\n";
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
header("Location: thankyou.html");
?>


HTML

<form method="POST" action="newsletter.php">
<input type="text" name="newsletter" title="" placeholder="Email Address..." required>
<button type="submit">Sign Up</button>
<div class="clearboth"></div>
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6Ldni7wUAAAAAKO37aO2hfy3kHyXTuN"></div>
<label><input name="consent" type="checkbox" class="input-name" required> 
<span class="captchaspan obligatorycheck"><!--Some text--></span>
</label>
</form>
```

Comment: You assign $_POST['email'] to $email variable, but you send $contact in $email_body instead

Comment: I have made the change and it still doesn't work even when I define $email

Comment: Please include your HTML form in the question

Comment: Check if $_POST['email'] is not empty. Maybe it is not passed from your form

Comment: `name="newsletter"`  "newsletter" != "email".  Either change the HTML field name or change the PHP `$_POST['email']`.  Voting to close as a typo.

Comment: @PatrickQ I have included the HTML

Comment: @PatrickQ That has worked perfectly.  Thank you.  Embarrassing mistake but thanks for that.

Answer (score -2):

```
$email_body = "Email: $contact \r\n";
```

You have never defined `$contact`.

Comment: Yeah that's my fault sorry.  It should be $email not $contact.  I will edit now but even when I define $email it still doesn't work.

Comment: @Ruin Yeah, maybe that was the issue?

Comment: No it still doesn't work even with $email defined

Comment: @Ruin Does `$_POST["email"]` actually contain a value?